# EXCEL: Icon Conditional Formatting Based on Range of Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I am creating a spreadsheet for work and I need to format cells such that I get a green check mark when the value in the cell is between 100 and 101, yellow ! if it is between 97 and 100, and red X if it is below 97. Is there a formula that can solve this for me? I need the rule to apply to multiple cells. Thanks!

Comment: I understand conditional formatting, just not how to achieve the desired range

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted or comment on how it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `More rules...` option at the bottom to define specifics.

[image: more rules]

and then add your conditions.  Be sure to change `Percent` to `Value`.

[image: conditions]